# jsonp failing in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, jsonp

**Edit:** this is working again in Version 19.0.1084.56 so i'm closing this.

I'm using Chrome 19.0.1084.52 and I'm finding chrome is just silently failing jsonp related code.

As a real world case (as my code is on a private server atm), Hitting http://tweet.seaofclouds.com/ with firefox seems to work fine but chrome just silently fails.

The script is not showing up in any of the tabs.

I've tried manually writing a  tag. I've tried jQuery.getJSON and jQuery.ajax

Nothing I've tried seems to get around it, except for the non practical method of running the code locally (file://)

Other than running chrome in disable-web-security mode (which I have not yet tried) is there any way to get chrome to work?

Comment: I see it in Chrome 19. Inspected and in network tab I see lots of json files loaded from api.twitter.com and one from search.twitter.com. Maybe elaborate a bit more on what's not working.

Comment: Can you post the actual code you are using to make the request, I had similar issues with jsonp at one point, and was eventualy fixed by changing a few of the request parameters.  Seeing the actual request code would be a big help

Comment: Fine in `20.0.1132.17 beta-m` - you're referring to the `search.json` callbacks?